# Ruby on Rails Rspec validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

validation

```
def active_consent_run
    return unless self.consent_run_id
    unless [
             ConsentRun::STATUS[:in_progress],
             ConsentRun::STATUS[:needs_witness_signature],
             ConsentRun::STATUS[:needs_researcher_signature]
           ].include?(self.consent_run.status)
      errors.add(:consent_run_id, 'needs to be in progress')
      false
    end
end
```

rspec test

```
it "#active_consent_run" do
  consent_run = create(:consent_run, :in_progress)
  consent_question = create(:consent_run_question,
     consent_run: consent_run)
  expect(consent_question.valid?).to eq false
  expect(consent_question.errors[:consent_run_id]).to \
     eq ('needs to be in progress')
end
```

I have this validation and i wrote a rspec test in rails but test keeps falling. Can someone help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: Please share what error do you get.

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(consent_question.valid?).to eq false
     
       expected: false
            got: true
     
       (compared using ==)

Comment: You have created the `consent_run` (whatever it means) with `:in_progress` passed. Pass another value if you want the test for `in_progress` to fail.

Comment: or when i put trait consented i get this error :
 Failure/Error: consent_question = create(:consent_run_question, consent_run: consent_run)
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Consent run needs to be in progress

Comment: i have this stats: STATUS = {
      in_progress: 0, # ConsentRun has started, but not completed
      needs_witness_signature: 1, # Patient signed, but not researcher
      needs_researcher_signature: 2, # Patient signed and witness (if required), but not researcher
      consented: 3, # User agreed to consent
      declined_consent: 4, # Patient did not agree to consent or did not pass questions
      removed_consent: 5 # Patient removed consent after consenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems you have to create the `consent_run` with the status `:in_progress`, *then* create a `consent_question`, and only *then* update the status of `consent_run` to be `invalid`:

```
it "#active_consent_run" do
  consent_run = create(:consent_run, :in_progress)
  consent_question = create(:consent_run_question,
    consent_run: consent_run)
  # I guess it’s an active record    ⇓ for illegal status
  consent_run.update_column :status, 4
  expect(consent_question.valid?).to eq false
  expect(consent_question.errors[:consent_run_id]).to \
    eq(['needs to be in progress'])
end
```

Comment: Failure/Error: consent_run.update_column :status, :removed_consent
     
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Column 'status' cannot be null: UPDATE `consent_runs` SET `consent_runs`.`status` = NULL WHERE `consent_runs`.`id` = 94
 
i got this error

Comment: OK, you likely have this column stored as integer in the database. I have updated an answer.

Comment: we are geting close :D 


Failure/Error: expect(consent_question.errors[:consent_run_id]).to eq ('needs to be in progress')
     
       expected: "needs to be in progress"
            got: ["needs to be in progress"]

Comment: Thank You! :) can i post another issue i have with sopes? same rspec, ruby on rails etc

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :by_trial_id, -> trial_id { joins(consent_run: :consent_form).where("consent_forms.trial_id = ?", trial_id) }
  scope :by_patient_id, -> patient_id { joins(:consent_run).where("consent_runs.patient_id = ?", patient_id) }
```

i have these scopes and i need to write a rspec test.